# Background overlay with responsive images

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have an image with a background overlay that needs to respond to screen devices.

The bg overly needs to remain full width but putting 100% width just creates an overflow on small devices and underflow on larger ones.

Appreciate the help.

Please see my [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S2yQg/)

```
.col-md-3{
    width:30%;
}
img{
    width:100%;
}
.brand-category{
    position: relative;
}
.brand-text{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(130,130,130,0.5);
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: -10px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Paddings cousing overflow

```
<div class="col-md-3 brand-category">
  <p class="brand-text"><span>Category</span></p>
  <a href=""><img src="http://paulobriendesign.com/img/paul-obrien.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

css

```
.col-md-3{
  width:30%;
}
img{
  width:100%;
}
.brand-category{
  position: relative;
}
.brand-text{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(130,130,130,0.5);
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: -10px;
}
.brand-text span {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XWfN4/

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `display:block;` to your `img` CSS

```
img{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
```

### [Demo Without](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/S2yQg/2/)

### [Demo With](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/S2yQg/3/)